# How to index json data in a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 10.7

I'm storing search results in the database in a search_history table:

columns:

```
id : character varying
date_inserted: date
search_json : json         # contains 6 search parameters all of which can be null
result_json : json         # search results
```

Each id can have multiple search_json values, so ideally I would have the primary key set to:   `id, search_json` but it is not possible to have a json column in a primary key

My question is what do I set my primary key to?
The best I can think of is to not store search_json and instead to create a columns for each of it's 6 search parameters and create a unique index on :

```
id, col1,col2,..,col6
```

and have no primary key, since a primary key can't contain null values.
This feels like a poor solution.
Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: You could use `jsonb` which allows for the creation of unique indexes (and thus PK constraints) The question is: how do you want to deal with the NULL values? Does the JSON value contain `"term1": null` or does it not contain the key at all?

Comment: I didn't know that, i'll give it a try, thanks. Both, I can have "term1":null or no "term1"

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name jsonb works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the size of the JSON value will be limited, you can switch to `jsonb` (which is recommended anyway) as that implements an equality operator, which is needed to support a unique constraint.

But this contains the risk that if someone stores a really large JSON value, the insert fails because it exceeds the maximum size of a single index entry (even though it would not be a duplicate).

However, you need to be aware that a value `{"term1": null, "term2": "*"}` will be considered different to `{"term2": "*"}`. Maybe you should "normalize" your JSON before storing it and remove all keys with a `NULL` value (e.g. using `jsonb_strip_nulls()`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on null values, i'll normalise as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I would introduce an artificial primary key, store the search columns as normal database columns rather than as JSON. That way you can always uniquely identify a row.